# sutta reference: forbidding to call the Buddha by name

Tags: reference-request, sutras

I've heard that there are suttas where the Buddha forbade people to call him by his given name. Which suttas are these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first occurred when he met the five ascetics after the enlightenment when they started calling him by his name Gotama before teaching his earliest discourse, Dhammacakkapavattana sutta.

> Bhikkus, do not address me by the name Gotama nor as a friend. I have
>   become a Perfect One, worthy of the great reverence.

Source: http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/damachak.pdf page 56

Answer (score 2):

This is found in the [Ariyapariyesana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.026.than.html), the [Bodhikumāra Sutta](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima2/085-bodhirajakumara-e1.html) and any other suttas that describe the Buddha's search for awakening.

> *Then, wandering by stages, I arrived at Varanasi, at the Deer Park in Isipatana, to where the group of five monks were staying. From afar
>   they saw me coming and, on seeing me, made a pact with one another,
>   (saying,) 'Friends, here comes Gotama the contemplative: living
>   luxuriously, straying from his exertion, backsliding into abundance.
>   He doesn't deserve to be bowed down to, to be greeted by standing up,
>   or to have his robe & bowl received. Still, a seat should be set out;
>   if he wants to, he can sit down.' But as I approached, they were
>   unable to keep to their pact. One, standing up to greet me, received
>   my robe & bowl. Another spread out a seat. Another set out water for
>   washing my feet. However, they addressed me by name and as 'friend.'*
>
> *So I said to them, 'Don't address the Tathagata  by name and as "friend."*